# Azure Service Fabric Cluster performance on Windows Server 2016 vs Windows Server 2019

Tags: azure-service-fabric, windows-server

We have API services running 24/7 on a Service Fabric Cluster in Azure on Windows Server 2016 without issue.  We recently created a new Service Fabric Cluster with Windows Server 2019 and twice the CPU cores and twice the RAM of the aforementioned cluster, and deployed the identical services to it.  When we run identical load tests against the two clusters, the older cluster with half the resources and Windows 2016 takes it all like a champ with no errors.  However the newer cluster with twice the resources and Windows Server 2019 throws 500 errors in about 20% of the calls.

As we can't find any other difference between the two clusters other than the Windows Server version, we can only imagine the issue to lie there somewhere.  Any thoughts on this?

Here is the full error message:

```
> Category: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpServer EventId:
> 2 RequestId: 80002a3f-0000-e600-b63f-84710c7967bb RequestPath:
> /api/v3/token SpanId: 03ebbbcf99657a40 TraceId:
> ad539f7a6f633c41a753a4513a864dd8 ParentId: 0000000000000000
> 
> Connection ID "16573246630334048248", Request ID
> "80002a3f-0000-e600-b63f-84710c7967bb": An unhandled exception was
> thrown by the application.
> 
> Exception:  System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred
> while sending the request.  ---> System.IO.IOException: The response
> ended prematurely.    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.FillAsync()   
> at
> System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ReadNextResponseHeaderLineAsync(Boolean
> foldedHeadersAllowed)    at
> System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    --- End of inner
> exception stack trace ---    at
> System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithNtConnectionAuthAsync(HttpConnection
> connection, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)  
> at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask,
> HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean
> disposeCts)    at
> ClientServiceClient.AuthenticateClientAsync(ClientAuthenticationRequest
> request)    at
> Application.V3.Controllers.TokenController.CreateToken() in
> C:\Source\Repos\src\Backend\Api\src\Application.Api\V3\Controllers\TokenController.cs:line
> 86    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper
> mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[]
> arguments)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Logged|12_1(ControllerActionInvoker
> invoker)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&
> next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker
> invoker)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint
> endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT`1.ProcessRequestAsync()
```

**EDIT #1**: Upon deeper inspection, it appears the new cluster does not have the Reverse Proxy enabled, whereas the old one does.  I have read documentation on Reverse Proxy, but I can't decipher from it whether this could cause an issue like this.  If anyone has experience with this parameter, please do let me know.

Comment: Did you have performance counters during your load test? Are you using the same service fabric version in both clusters? Did you compare cluster setup?

Comment: Yes, yes, and yes.  :)

Comment: Did you ran the tests again with reverse proxy? Out of curiosity.

Comment: After further testing, we feel as though there was something seriously wrong with the VM cluster that we spun up.  The errors we were getting just didn't make any sense.  So we tore it down and stood up a new one.  The issue no longer exists with the new.